# Javascript string.match() equivalent in PHP Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple javascript function for counting string length containing emojis. It is working great in javascript. How can I write an alternate of this in PHP? I tried `preg_grep()` but that didn't come handy.

Here is my javascript function:

```
function length(str){
    if(!str) return 0;
    var astralRange = /\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?=\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])|(?:[^\ud800-\udfff][\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]?|[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\ud800-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*/g;
    if (typeof str !== "string") {
        throw new Error("Input must be a string");
    }
    return str.match(astralRange).length;
}
```

I tried this in PHP (error one):

```
function unicode_strlen($str){
    $astralRange =  '/\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?=\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])|(?:[^\ud800-\udfff][\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]?|[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\ud800-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*/g';
    $array = preg_grep($astralRange, $str);
    return count($array);
}
```

But that is not working. I got this error.

```
Warning: preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /Users/sibidharan/websites/unicode/index.php on line 8
```

I know it expects 2nd parameter to be array. Whatsoever, how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

```
function unicode_strlen($str){
    $astralRange =  '/\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff](?=\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])|(?:[^\ud800-\udfff][\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]?|[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\ud800-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*/';
    preg_match_all($astralRange, $str, $array);
    return count($array);
}

echo unicode_strlen("✌");
```

It generated a PHP warning

```
preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1
```

How can I now port the regexp to compile with `preg_match_all()`

Comment: I think you are looking for preg_match function.

Comment: @BorisSavic preg_match returns int which says if the pattern is present or not. I think that won't work!

Comment: Read `preg_match` manual __again__

Comment: Yes, but look at third param of preg_match. preg_match ($pattern, $subject, $matches);

Comment: I tried `preg_match($astralRange, $str, $array, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);` , but I got error `Unknown modifier g`